# Why does this new column infection_rate all show 0s?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, numeric, sqldatatypes

Just as the title says. If I had to guess, I would think maybe it's because the values are too small and they're getting rounded off to 0? But then that wouldn't make sense because with the values seen in the picture, the infection_rate should be around 3 percent?  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv1HX.png)

I've tried to re-import the csv data as numeric(18,0) and decimal(18,10) but I'm still getting 0's after the calculation. I'm not sure how to change the data type of the column without re-importing the entire csv.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Change 100 to 100.0 - If you divide 2 ints, SQL Server returns an int, as soon as one is a decimal you will get a decimal result.